# Move table from 1 table to another for millions of record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to move data from 1 table to another, but they table contains millions of record and it might be getting used.

So, I do not want to move all data at one time, kind of thinking about a loop where i move first few rows, then other few rows.

So that the table do not get locked.

The normal query would be something like this

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
SELECT <columns>
FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;

COMMIT;
```

But, can anyone suggest, for millions of rows, how can i move few rows in a loop format ?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but wouldn't a delete with top + output work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this article http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/transferring-large-amounts-of-data-using-batch-inserts 
they are using a while loop, please take time to read the comments too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 1;
while (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
Drop table #t;
SELECT top(10)  <columns> into #t FROM Table1 WHERE <condition>; 

INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
Select * from #t

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE idcol in(select idcol from #t);
End
```

Try this query. It will insert 10 rows at a time.